# How to build an array of array using two for loops in Angular?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I want to build an array of array in typescript using two for loops

```
 imageUploaded: any = [];

 setupImageData() {
    let tempObj;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.imageData.length; i++) {
      tempObj = this.imageData[i];

      this.imageUploaded[tempObj.imageTypeName] = [];
      
      for (var j = 0; j < tempObj.maxCount; j++) {
        this.imageUploaded[tempObj.imageTypeName][j] = '';
      }
    }
 }
```

the output i get is an array of array. But in HTML when i print as

```
EX: tempObj.imageTypeName = 'Front'

{{imageUploaded['Front'][0]}}
```

but i get the error as 'TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined'.
What should i change to print like this in HTML?

Comment: It looks like `imageUploaded` is an object/dictionary. Can you please give the output of only `{{imageUploaded | json}}`

Comment: rememeber that you only can show it **after** has value, so is possible you need make some like `<ng-container *ngIf="imageUploader">{{imageLoaded['Front'][0]}}</ng-container>`

Comment: ``` {{imageUploaded | json}} ``` gives an empty array '[]'.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use an array, because you could just use [Maps](https://howtodoinjava.com/typescript/maps/) instead, it is a lot easier to work with.

Comment: Is there even anything inside `imageData`? When is `setupImageData` called?

Comment: setupImageData is called while opening a form. this for has different sections. each section has maxCount of images that can be uploaded. Here ImageUploaded is the array of sections(Ex. 'Front') and each section must be an array. If maxCount of 'Front' section is 2. the user will add two image under front section.